# How to extract href when ['href'] element is a hyperlink

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, onclick, href

I'm trying to scrape data from a webpage, and move on to the next page by extracting the href to the next page.

However, the  tag containing the href to the next page in this case is href='#next'.
Upon inspecting this element with Chrome, when I hover over the word '#next' it appears to be a hyperlink that shows me the complete href.

I suspect that the href is lost once I make a request and convert it to text like so;

```
r = requests.get(url)

s = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
```

I use `findAll()` function to get the element I'm looking for:

```
s.findAll('a', class_='pagenav')[5]
```

result:

```
a href="#next" class="pagenav" title="next page" onclick="javascript:
document.pageForm.limitstart.value=20; document.pageForm.submit();return false;">
Next&nbsp;&gt;
```

How can I get the href in this case?

This is the link to the site

https://associatedrealtorsaruba.com/index.php?option=com_ezrealty&Itemid=11&task=results&cnid=0&custom7=&custom8=&parking=&type=0&cid=0&stid=0&locid=0&minprice=&maxprice=&minbed=&maxbed=&min_squarefeet=&max_squarefeet=&bathrooms=&sold=0&lug=0&featured=0&custom4=&custom5=&custom6=&postcode=&radius=&direction=DEFAULT&submit=Search

Comment: You can't navigate using that `href `value.Because it is a `javascripts` onclick event.However if your url is public you can share so OP might help you.

Comment: `JavaScript` can add url to this element but BeautifulSoup can't run JavaScript - you may need `Selenium` to control web browser which can run JavaScript

Comment: If this page use JavaScript with `pageForm` then maybe url is somewhere in `<form action="url">` tag

Comment: @furas I tried with Selenium importing webdriver to run Firefox() and then .execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML") to get the html behind the javascript. But I get the same results using .find('a', class_='pagenav'). I did notice new <a> tags appear in the new html namely: <a> class="prevLink", however, it's href='#'

Comment: if you use `Selenium` then use `Selenium` to find `<a class="pagenav">`  or `<a title="next page">` and `.click()` it to load next page and you don't have to get `href` for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Selenium` then use `Selenium` to find `<a class="pagenav">` or `<a title="next page">` and `.click()` it to load next page and you don't have to get `href` for this.

```
import selenium.webdriver

url = 'https://associatedrealtorsaruba.com/index.php?option=com_ezrealty&Itemid=11&task=results&cnid=0&custom7=&custom8=&parking=&type=0&cid=0&stid=0&locid=0&minprice=&maxprice=&minbed=&maxbed=&min_squarefeet=&max_squarefeet=&bathrooms=&sold=0&lug=0&featured=0&custom4=&custom5=&custom6=&postcode=&radius=&direction=DEFAULT&submit=Search'

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

# find link to next page
next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="next page"]')

# click link to load next page
next_page.click()
```

---

**BTW:** If you load manually page 1, 2 and 3 and compare they urls in browser then you will see the only difference in urls

```
for page 1: &limitstart=0 
for page 2: &limitstart=20 
for page 3: &limitstart=40
```

and this is the method to load next page without getting `href` - you have to get original url and add `&limitstart=` with correct value to load different page.

---

If you want to display 50 items on page then you have to use `&limit=50` and then `&limitstart` will have to use values 0, 50, 100, etc.

---

**EDIT:**

With Requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'https://associatedrealtorsaruba.com/index.php?option=com_ezrealty&Itemid=11&task=results&cnid=0&custom7=&custom8=&parking=&type=0&cid=0&stid=0&locid=0&minprice=&maxprice=&minbed=&maxbed=&min_squarefeet=&max_squarefeet=&bathrooms=&sold=0&lug=0&featured=0&custom4=&custom5=&custom6=&postcode=&radius=&direction=DEFAULT&submit=Search'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0', # need full UA
}

for x in (0, 20, 40):
    r = requests.get(url + '&limitstart={}'.format(x), headers=headers)
    print('\n---', x, '---\n')

    soup = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')

    all_items = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'h3'})
    for item in all_items:
        print(item.get_text(strip=True))
```

With Selenium

```
import selenium.webdriver

url = 'https://associatedrealtorsaruba.com/index.php?option=com_ezrealty&Itemid=11&task=results&cnid=0&custom7=&custom8=&parking=&type=0&cid=0&stid=0&locid=0&minprice=&maxprice=&minbed=&maxbed=&min_squarefeet=&max_squarefeet=&bathrooms=&sold=0&lug=0&featured=0&custom4=&custom5=&custom6=&postcode=&radius=&direction=DEFAULT&submit=Search'

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

while True:

    all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="h3"]')
    for item in all_items:
        print(item.text)

    try:    
        # find link to next page
        all_items = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="next page"]')

        # click link to load next page
        all_items.click()
    except Exception as ex:
        print('ex:', ex)
        break
```